# How is group theory (and matrices) used in symmetry operations?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, symmetry, group-theory

I am a high school IB student. For my 2-year math course, there is an internal assessment called "exploration" which should be max. 12 pages long. The goal of this assignment is for students to explore areas or uses of mathematics beyond the course.

Now onto the important stuff. After doing some research on topics to investigate in linear algebra, number theory, graph theory or group theory, I came across a potential subject: "Investigating the use of group theory (and of matrices) in symmetry operations in chemistry." 
I know my question very broad but I am here looking for material to learn from. Please post any useful links or names of topics to look at please!

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19477/symmetry-representations

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based/too broad, there are too many equally valid answers. It would suit a forum very well, but probably not Stack Exchange. On topic, you're better served by looking up a good textbook on the matter. Cotton's *Chemical Applications of Group Theory* is the classic, but it is rather tough to read, I don't expect an IB student to be able to read it. The group theory chapter in Atkins' *Molecular Quantum Mechanics* might be more accessible. As for websites, a simple Google search for "molecular symmetry and group theory" should turn up plenty of resources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resources for learning Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry)

Comment: also have a look at the answers/comments  to this question https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58609/understanding-group-theory-easily-and-quickly/58613#58613